# JBoss HTTP Server Hanging With The Following Thread Dump

Tags: multithreading, performance, jboss, freeze, slowdown

Our Jboss Instance is hanging and when I look at the jstack of the threads, I see a lot of this

What does this indicate ? Is there a problem with my configuration ? My jboss is currently load balanced through Apache Tomcat...

Can anyone help me understand what is the cause of this ?
I'm using Jboss 6.1 for my application server version...

Apache is used to load balance the requsts to three Jboss Servers. I end up with a lot of this in my dumps

```
"http-49173-43" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007f71a8048000 nid=0x4594 runnable [0x00007f709a7e6000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:129)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalInputBuffer.fill(InternalInputBuffer.java:729)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalInputBuffer.parseRequestLine(InternalInputBuffer.java:366)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:790)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:598)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a nice Blog entry on Javacodegeeks of [How to analyze Thread Dump](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/07/how-to-analyze-thread-dump-thread-stack.html) 
Another more detailed one you can find on [dzone.com](http://architects.dzone.com/articles/how-analyze-java-thread-dumps)

In your case your Thread is reading input from a Socket and it's quite normal that there are many threads on an application server waiting for HTTP input.